# getting "cookies must be enabled to use github" when i am trying to trigger github pileine using aws lambda

Tags: python, github, aws-lambda, lambda, github-actions

I am trying to setup an automation so that my lambda runs every day and trigger github pipeline, i generated PAT on github and using it in my lambda env variable but i keep on getting cookies must be enabled error.

```
 import os
 import requests
 import json

 def lambda_handler(event, context):
     # GitHub repository URL
     github_repo_url = "https://github.com/my-repo/actions/workflows/packer.yml/dispatches"

# GitHub personal access token (PAT)
github_token = os.environ.get('GITHUB_TOKEN')
if not github_token:
    return {
        "statusCode": 400,
        "body": "GitHub token not found in Lambda environment."
    }

# Event type and client payload
event_type = "manual-trigger"
client_payload = {"event_type": event_type}

headers = {
    "Authorization": f"Bearer {github_token}",
    "User-Agent": "AWS-Lambda-Function",
    "Accept": "application/vnd.github.v3+json",
    "Content-Type": "application/json"
}

# Trigger the GitHub Actions workflow using a POST request
response = requests.post(github_repo_url, headers=headers, json=client_payload)

if response.status_code == 204:
    return {
        "statusCode": 200,
        "body": "GitHub Actions workflow triggered successfully."
    }
else:
    return {
        "statusCode": response.status_code,
        "body": f"Failed to trigger GitHub Actions workflow. Response: {response.text}"
    }
```

Comment: Are you using the lambda handler, just as a schedule without any logic? Because you can have schedules in github actions.